# Метод stats.get в VK API

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Добрый день, не могу разобраться. В VK API есть метод `stats.get` у которого есть параметры : **group_id , app_id , date_from , date_to**.
Собственно , в чем заключается сложность. Я сделал сбор групп и вывод их. Теперь хочу для каждой группы сделать и статистику, чтобы выдавало сколько в группе за сегодняшний день было заходов, просмотров и так далее(все что может выдать `stats.get`. 
Получаю список групп, через метод `groups.get`, а вывожу каждую через `foreach`.
Я немного не понимаю, как сделать так, чтобы ID групп подставлялись автоматически для каждой из групп. (пример ниже)
[image: пример]

Самое главное, чтобы это выполнялось автоматически, не нужно было в ручную для каждого метода `stats.get` прописывать ID группы. Список ID групп я получаю с помощью метода `groups.get`. В самом методе `stats.get`, есть все нужные результаты , которые мне нужны. Буду благодарен за помощь.

Получение групп `groups.get` и `foreach`:

```
$fields = [
    'id', 'name', 'screen_name', 'photo_100', 
    'members_count', 'site'
];

$request_params = [
    'user_id' => $token['user_id'],
    'extended' => '1',
    'filter' => 'admin',
    'fields' => implode(',', $fields),
    'access_token' => $token['access_token'],
    'count' => '200',
];

$url = "https://api.vk.com/method/groups.get?" . http_build_query($request_params);


$result = file_get_contents($url);
$decode = json_decode($result);
foreach ($decode->response as $result) {
    $name = $result->name;
    $screen_name = $result->screen_name;
    $photo100 = $result->photo_100;
    $id = $result->gid;
    $members_count = $result->members_count;
    $site = $result->site;
    $all_member_count += $members_count; //Получаем общее число подписчиков


    echo '<img src="' . $photo100 . '" />';
    echo "<p>ID : ".$id."</p>";
    echo "<p>Просмотров : ".$views."</p>";
    echo "<p>Подписчиков :".$members_count."</p>";
    echo "<p>Название : " .$name. "</p>"."<br>"."<hr>";
}
```

Вот код с запросом stats.get :

```
$fields = [
                        'id', 'name', 'screen_name', 'photo_100', 'members_count', 'site'
                        ];

                    $request_params = [
                        'user_id' => $token['user_id'],
                        'extended' => '1',
                        'filter' => 'admin',
                        'fields' => implode(',', $fields),
                        'access_token' => $token['access_token'],
                        'count' => '150',

                    ];

                    $url = "https://api.vk.com/method/groups.get?" . http_build_query($request_params);


                    $result = file_get_contents($url);
                    $decode = json_decode($result);
                    foreach ($decode->response as $result) {
                    $name = $result->name;
                    $screen_name = $result->screen_name;
                    $photo100 = $result->photo_100;
                    $id = $result->gid;
                    $members_count = $result->members_count;
                    $site = $result->site;
                    $all_member_count += $members_count; //Получаем общее число подписчиков

                    $request_params_for_stats = [
                        'access_token' => $token['access_token'],
                        'group_id' => $id,
                        'date_from' => $date_today,
                        'date_to' => $date_today,

                    ];

                    $url_for_stats = "https://api.vk.com/method/stats.get?" . http_build_query($request_params_for_stats);  
                    $result_stats = file_get_contents($url_for_stats);
                    $decode_stats = json_decode($result_stats);
                    foreach ($decode_stats->response as $stats_result)
                    $views = $stats_result->views;





                    echo '<img src="' . $photo100 . '" />';  
                    echo "<p>ID : ".$id."</p>"; 
                    echo "<p>Просмотров : ".$views."</p>"; 
                    echo "<p>Подписчиков :".$members_count."</p>";
                    echo "<p>Название : " .$name. "</p>"."<br>"."<hr>";

                    };
```

Comment: Вроде просто внутри каждой итерации цикла нужно составлять и отправлять запрос к api с учётом id группы (id группы известно внутри итерации). А вообще, покажи код: как ты обрабатывает результат метода `groups.get`, ну и свой `foreach` покажи.

Comment: @diraria, добрый день, сейчас добавлю код

Comment: Отлично. Тебе нужно на каждой итерации цикла отправлять запрос `stats.get` для группы, соответствующей этой итерации. Так и сделай: добавь перед блоком `echo` ещё одни `$request_params` (только назови переменную по другому, скажем `$request_params_for_stats`). В них будет в том числе id группы (`$request_params_for_stats = ['group_id' => $id, ...]`). Далее по этим` `$request_params_for_stats` формируешь `$url_for_stats` , затем опять отправляешь запрос через `file_get_contents`, ну и получаешь ответ с нужной тебе информацией о группе.

Comment: @diraria, спасибо большое, сейчас попробую, надеюсь что получится! Если что отпишу сюда, что не получается!

Comment: @diraria, я добавил в тему свой код, который сейчас. Вроде как все работает, спасибо большое при большое! 
Но теперь есть одна проблема, есть группы, в которых нет статистики, т.е там нету просмотров и не от куда брать числа. И получается так, что он берет статистику с прошлой группы. Например: Идут группы по порядку. Группа 1 - Просмотров : 42 , Группа 2 - Просмотров : 42 , но в Группе 2 нет просмотров , неоткуда брать значения `{"response":[]} ` выдает.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю второй `foreach` не нужен, так как массив будет либо пустым (если статистика группы недоступна), либо будет состоять из одного элемента. Поэтому нужно с помощью `if` проверить, пуст ли массив, и записать в `$views` текст вроде "не удалось получить число просмотров", если пуст или значение из первого элемента массива.

Comment: @diraria , без второго `foreach` почему-то не работает, но с ним все выдается. Пробую сейчас сделать с помощью `if` , но пока не получается. Пробовал через `empty`, но тоже никак.

Comment: @diraria, чет не получается сделать проверку. Сейчас попробую без второго foreach сделать, посмотрим что выйдет. Вроде как не получалось тоже.

Comment: @diraria, все не могу понять, почему он берет значения из прошлого положительного массива? Ставлю проверку, он её игнорирует. 
`if(count($views)<1)` `{ $views = "Нет статистики для данного сообщества";` Вот проверка, правильно?

Comment: Для групп с недоступной статистикой берётся значение просмотров из предыдущей группы, потому что для таких групп массив `$decode_stats->response` будет пустым и внутрь `foreach` код не зайдёт (соответственно значение `$value` не изменится). Второй `foreach` точно-точно здесь не нужен. Проверка не совсем правильная, у тебя `$views` это ведь не массив, а число, а для чисел функция `count` всегда возвращает один. Должно быть что-то вроде `if (empty($decode_stats->response)) ...`.

Comment: @diraria, хорошо, спасибо.
Сегодня попробую , если что-то опять не получится отпишу.

Comment: @diraria, мы можем как нибудь связаться? Я бы хотел код показать. А то совсем все плохо.

Comment: Например, https://vk.com/write104171944